# sum up rows column-wise in R

Tags: r, dplyr

for a tibble like this,

```
# A tibble: 54,173 x 42
# Groups:   transcript_id [32,834]
   transcript_id Rep1_Ws.2_NT.0h… Rep1_Ws.2_PopP2… Rep1_Ws.2_PopP2…
   <chr>                    <int>            <int>            <int>
 1 AT2G08655                    0                0                0
 2 AT4G04480                    0                0                0
 3 AT1G31380                    0                0                0
 4 AT1G03340                    0                0                0
 5 AT1G04440                   10                6               19
 6 AT5G13090                    8                1                0
 7 AT2G30190                    0                0                0
 8 AT1G31390                    0                0                0
 9 AT1G04487                    0                1                0
10 AT3G10680                    0                0                0



tibble %>% group_by(transcript_id) %>% summarize(Rep1_Ws.2_NT.0h… = sum(Rep1_Ws.2_NT.0h…))
```

can only sum up a column a time. what if I want to summarize all the columns?

Comment: Does `colSums` do what you need?

Comment: the first column is no numeric, throws an error

Comment: `tibble %>% group_by(transcript_id) %>% summarize_all(sum)`?

Comment: How about excluding the first column: `colSums(df[-1])`?

Comment: sovled by tibble %>% group_by(transcript_id) %>% summarize_all(sum)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this in the tidyverse:

```
tibble %>% 
  group_by(transcript_id) %>% 
  summarize_all(sum)
```

In base R, one could use `colSums`, excluding the first non-numeric column:

```
colSums(tibble[-1])
```